# How to dynamically change $table name in Laravel Model?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to pull data from a table which keeps changing its suffix based on date. for example Report201906 for June, Report201907 for July.

So I want to connect to a table with the current date suffix. e.g current month is July. So I want to connect to Report201907

I tried:

```
protected $connection = 'mysql2';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
protected $current_month = date('Ym',strtotime(date('Y-m')." -1 month"));
protected $table = 'Report'.$current_month; //Hoping to connect to Report201907
```

But I get the Error 
Constant expression contains invalid operations. I'm pretty new to laravel and PHP.Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can't assign it directly to the property, but you could set it in the constructor

Comment: I hate to be 'that guy' but why do you want a report stored under a date-specific table? It is not called a relational database for no reason ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need laravel Eloquent or Model for what you require, For RAW SQL queries, just `use` laravel `DB` facade in your controller.

use the facade in your controller like:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

public function index() {

   $current_month = date('Ym',strtotime(date('Y-m')." -1 month"));

   $table = 'Report'.$current_month;    // btw this returns 'Report201906' not 'Report201907'

   $records = DB::select('select * from '.$table);

   return $records;

}
```

for details please official documentation: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database

Comment: I have to use the Eloquent Model reference since its a connection to another database server. different connection from primary. so DB::select will not work in this case. So i'm forced to invoke the Model directly

Comment: @Vester you can use multiple database connections with `DB` facade as well. 
    
    `$users = DB::connection('foo')->select(...);`

ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#using-multiple-database-connections

Comment: Thanks for suggestions everyone. I managed to get it working by declaring the values inside a default constructor.